# Ошибка в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Делаю `ListView` со значками, но на строчке

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item,  images, point);
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(ru.ххх.название приложения.название активности, int, int[], java.lang.String[])'
```

Как я понял, нужно ввести ещё какое то значение int, но так и не понял какое.

Вот основной код активности, может будет нужен

```
String[] point = {"1", "2","3","4","5",};
int [] images = {R.drawable.1,
        R.drawable.2,
        R.drawable.3,
        R.drawable.4,
        R.drawable.5 };
Intent intent; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item,  images, point);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Ругается, потому что не ArrayAdapter не имеет такого конструктора. Перейдите в сам класс и посмотрите доступные(Ctrl+ЛКМ по классу)

Comment: третьим аргументом адаптера (который у вас `images`) в ArrayAdapter может быть ID-ресурса - ссылка на один виджет TextView в вашей кастомной разметке, но никак не массив ссылок и не на виджеты ImageView. Видимо вы путаете его с SimpleAdapter, это не одно и то же и конструкторы у них разные